# What are the parentheses for at the end of Python method names?

Tags: python, class, methods, parentheses

I'm a beginner to Python and programming in general. Right now, I'm having trouble understanding the function of empty parentheses at the end of method names, built-in or user-created. For example, if I write:

```
print "This string will now be uppercase".upper()
```

...why is there an empty pair of parentheses after "upper?" Does it do anything? Is there a situation in which one would put something in there? Thanks!

Comment: If you're a beginner, you can learn about a lot of basic concepts in the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the parentheses indicate that you want to call the method

`upper()` returns the value of the method applied to the string

if you simply say `upper`, then it returns a method, not the value you get when the method is applied

```
>>> print "This string will now be uppercase".upper
<built-in method upper of str object at 0x7ff41585fe40>
>>>
```

Answer (score 16):

Because *without* those you are only referencing the method object. *With* them you tell Python you wanted to call the method.

In Python, functions and methods are first-order objects. You can store the method for later use without calling it, for example:

```
>>> "This string will now be uppercase".upper
<built-in method upper of str object at 0x1046c4270>
>>> get_uppercase = "This string will now be uppercase".upper
>>> get_uppercase()
'THIS STRING WILL NOW BE UPPERCASE'
```

Here `get_uppercase` stores a reference to the bound `str.upper` method of your string. Only when we then add `()` after the reference is the method actually called.

That the method takes no arguments here makes no difference. You still need to tell Python to do the actual call.

The `(...)` part then, is called a [*Call* expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls), listed explicitly as a separate type of expression in the Python documentation:

> A *call* calls a callable object (e.g., a *function*) with a possibly empty series of *arguments*.

Comment: This makes sense to me when I can think of the attribute as a verb, but is there a good way of remembering which attributes that aren't verbs are methods, or is it just whatever the library author wanted?  For example, for a NumPy array ```arr```,  ```arr.shape``` is a tuple indicating its shape, BUT for a dictionary ```d```, ```d.keys()```  is a list of its keys.  I've become accustomed to these two, but in general for attributes I use less often, I usually have to look up whether or not to include the parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

`upper()` is a **command** asking the upper method to run, while `upper` is a **reference** to the method itself.  For example,

```
upper2 = 'Michael'.upper
upper2() # does the same thing as 'Michael'.upper() !
```