# How the parenthesis are used right after the object's name?

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, pytorch

I want to know about the parenthesis after the Object's name.

I am learning AI and building the AI model, now in the Tutorial's code the author has written a line which is containing the Parenthesis right after the object's name which is : self.model(...)

Where self.model is the Object of the Network class.
How the objects are having parenthesis being an object, not a function?
Now I want to know about the parenthesis after the Object's name.

```
class Network(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self, input_size, nb_action):
        super(Network, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.nb_action = nb_action
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, 30)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(30, nb_action)

    def forward(self, state):
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(state))
        q_values = self.fc2(x)
        return q_values

class Dqn():

    def __init__(self, input_size, nb_action, gamma):
        self.gamma = gamma
        self.reward_window = []
        self.model = Network(input_size, nb_action)
        self.memory = ReplayMemory(100000)
        self.optimizer = optim.Adam(self.model.parameters(), lr = 0.001)
        self.last_state = torch.Tensor(input_size).unsqueeze(0)
        self.last_action = 0
        self.last_reward = 0

    def select_action(self, state):
        probs = F.softmax(self.model(Variable(state, volatile = True))*100) # <-- The problem is here where the self.model object is CALLED with Parenthesis.
        action = probs.multinomial(10)
        return action.data[0,0]
```

Comment: The parentheses are calling the constructor (`__init__`) of `Network`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32129064/what-are-the-parentheses-for-at-the-end-of-python-method-names

Comment: The parentheses after the class name in the class definition `class Dqn()` allow for the inclusion of 'parent' objects whose methods which will be inherited by the child object. As @iz_ alluded to, when you instantiate the object (e.g. `dq = Dqn(x,y,z)`), the parentheses are for passing arguments (except for self, which is implied), to the class' `__init__` method.

Comment: @iz_ No, techinically it is calling `type.__call__(Network, input_size, nb_action)`, which calls `Network.__new__(Network, input_size, nb_action)` and, if `Network.__new__` does indeed return an instance of `Network`, *then* calls `Network.__init__` on that instance.

Comment: But , in the code an Object self.model was already Initialized with Network class on the line : self.model = Network(size,action) , but after already called __init__ on the initilization , how can we put the parenthesis after the object itself ? LIKE : self.model() .... ? Please simplify ... I'm not that good...@Deepstop

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the correction; I was trying to make it easy to understand for OP.

Comment: @AAYUSHSHAH My guess is that `Network`'s base class (`nn.Module`) is callable, i.e. it defines `__call__`.

Comment: Can you simplify your answer for me please ? @chepner

Comment: I believe @iz_ simplified chepners comment earlier

Comment: @AAYUSHSHAH *All* types are callable; `type.__call__` is defined as it is so that you can get an instance of a class without having to call the class's `__new__` method manually.

Answer (score 1):

In python, everything is an object. The functions you create and call are also objects. Anything in python that can be called is a **callable object**.

However, if you want a class object in python to be a callable object, the `__call__` method must be defined inside the class.

When the object is called, the `__call__(self, ...)` method gets called.

Here is an example.

```py
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x=0):
        self.x = x

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.x})'

    def __call__(self, *args):
        print(f'{self} has been called with {args} as arguments')


f1 = Foo(5)
f2 = Foo()

f1()  # f1.__call__()
f2()  # f2.__call__()
f1(1, 2, 3)  # f1.__call__(1, 2, 3)
f2(10, 20)  # f2.__call__(10, 20)
```

Output:

```
Foo(5) has been called with () as arguments
Foo(0) has been called with () as arguments
Foo(5) has been called with (1, 2, 3) as arguments
Foo(0) has been called with (10, 20) as arguments
```

This is how you can make a python object a callable object.

Answer (score 0):

Any class can define a `__call__` method to define what it means for one of its instances to be called as if it were a function. In this case,

```
self.model(...)
```

works because it is short for `self.model.__call__(...)`, and `Network` inherits, via its base class, a definition of `__call__`.

---

In fact, this is why functions themselves are callable:

```
>>> def foo(): return 3
...
>>> type(foo)
<class 'function'>
>>> type(foo).__call__
<slot wrapper '__call__' of 'function' objects>
>>> foo()
3
>>> foo.__call__()
3
```

(Even `foo.__call__.__call__()` returns 3! Try not to think too hard about why `__call__` itself can be called. At some point, the Python implementation itself breaks the seemingly infinite chain of implicitly-invoked methods.)